# Logical operations in OpenCV from Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv, logical-operators

In OpenCV's C++ API, one can do elementwise boolean operations (and, or, xor, not) using a syntax like this:

```
Mat a, b;
Mat c = a & b;
```

and similarly with the others. I know there is no operator overloading in Java; I'm looking for how the Java API exposes the same functionality that was exposed in C++ in that form. I've found the `Core.bitwise_*` functions already, but those are per bit, not per matrix element.

Comment: there are no real bits in opencv, one element(byte) is the smallest item (for a binary Mat it's either 0 or 255). so , those functions are equivalent to the c++ version.

Comment: ... I see. I think I was imagining the existence of some mythical "behaves like C's non-bitwise OR, elementwise on arrays" operation and thought that operator overloading in the C++ API was doing just that, while in fact that one is bitwise, too. Thanks for pointing it out (would you like to write it up as a to-be-accepted answer?)

Answer (score 2):

This is operator overloading. In java operator overloading is not supported. But if you require something like this you can introduce a method to do this.

For example -

```
Mat a, b;
Mat c;
c = Mat.doOperation(a, b);
```

Where doOperation() is a static method in `Mat` -

```
public static doOperation(Mat a, Mat b){
   //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: thanks! I see that this is the way one would add such an operation, however, what I'm after is whether it's implemented already, that is, how to access the existing functionality in OpenCV. (I edited the question to make the intent less ambiguous.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat a, b; // Set these to what you need.
Mat result = new Mat();
Core.bitwise_and(a, b, result);
```

You can do the same with Core.bitwise_or(...)